# Make a delay after falling edge of signal and then do something in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I would like to know how I can do the following operations in this order:

**First** detect the falling edge of an input signal (`rd`), **then** wait for `15 ns` and **finally** make the necessary changes in the variables, for example store the `db_input` 8bits vector into `db_output` 8bits vector.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ent1 is
    port
    (
        -- Input ports
        rd              : in std_logic;
        db_input        : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

        -- Output ports
        db_output   : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0')
    );
end ent1;

architecture arch1 of ent1 is
begin

    process(rd)
    begin
        if (falling_edge(rd)) then
            -- Wait for 15 ns
            -- After the 15 ns save db_input into db_output
        end if;
    end process;
    
end arch1;
```

Comment: are you trying to do this on an FPGA? without a clock that is somehow related to 15ns this will not be possible.

Comment: unless you are literally trying to delay the signal by 15ns in your VHDL code only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you asked for:

```vhdl
process
begin
  wait until falling_edge(rd);
  wait for 15 ns;
  db_output <= db_input;
end process;
```